# Is it possible to use AWS's transcoding service with Google Storage?

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-compute-engine

I have a system built on top of Google's services, however AWS seems to have a terrific setup for video utilities (https://aws.amazon.com/elastictranscoder/ and https://aws.amazon.com/mediaconvert/). Is it possible to send my users' video from GCP to AWS and back again?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it if you use Google Cloud Storage and Amazon S3 to store and exchange data between clouds.

Have a look at the [gsutil command line](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/interoperability#using_the_gsutil_command_line) documentation:

> The gsutil tool lets you access Cloud Storage from the command line.
>   It can also be used to access and work with other cloud storage
>   services that use HMAC authentication, like Amazon S3. For example,
>   **after you add your Amazon S3 credentials to the .boto configuration
>   file for gsutil, you can start using gsutil to manage objects in your
>   Amazon S3 buckets**.

To do it, follow [Setting Up Credentials to Access Protected Data](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil_install#authenticate) guide, then go to your `~/.boto` file and find these lines:

```
# To add HMAC aws credentials for "s3://" URIs, edit and uncomment the
#aws_access_key_id = <your aws access key ID>
#aws_secret_access_key = <your aws secret access key>
```

fill in the `aws_access_key_id` and `aws_secret_access_key` settings with your S3 credentials.

After that, you'll be able **to copy from S3 to GCS or vice versa**:

```
gsutil cp -R s3://my-aws-bucket gs://my-gcp-bucket
```

> **If you have a large number of files to transfer** you might want to use
>   the top-level gsutil -m option (see gsutil help options), to perform a
>   parallel (multi-threaded/multi-processing) copy:

```
gsutil -m cp -R s3://my-aws-bucket gs://my-gcp-bucket
```

for more information check [`gsutil cp` documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp).

Also, you can use `gsutil rsync` command **to synchronizes data** between S3 and GCP:

```
gsutil rsync -d -r s3://my-aws-bucket gs://my-gcp-bucket
```

for more information check [`gsutil rsync` documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/rsync).